# Running GoogleApiClient on Thread results in error

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am new to android. I am trying to display current location in my MainActivity.
But as my network is slow I am getting the entire front end very late. So i decided to use Threads. So my location based part of the code runs silently in the background.Things worked Perfectly but my OnResume function throws an error. And I am not sure how to proceed further about it.

My Thread code in MainActivity OnCreate:

```
UserLocationDetails locationDetails=new UserLocationDetails();
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    TextView userLocationView;
    Button settings;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Runnable runnable=new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                mGoogleApiClient=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this).
                        addConnectionCallbacks(MainActivity.this).
                        addOnConnectionFailedListener(MainActivity.this).
                        addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
                mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
                        .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                        .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds


            }
        };

        Thread googleApiClientThread=new Thread(runnable);
        googleApiClientThread.start();
```

OnResume Function:

```
  @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        Log.i(TAG, "OnResume, Connected back!");
    }
```

Logcat Error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.connect()' on a null object reference
            at androidfactory.mafi.com.wru.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:113)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1280)
            at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6096)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3011)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3063)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2418)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Answer (score 1):

Null Pointer Exception is thrown because in onResume() it is trying to call method on mGoogleApiClient, but it is not created as its creation is done inside of Runnable background thread, so there is asynchronous execution of code.

you can check before calling connect() for null reference.

```
   protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
     if(mGoogleApiClient != null){
          mGoogleApiClient.connect();
          Log.i(TAG, "OnResume, Connected back!");
     }

}
```

Comment: If its NOT NULL , why should I connect again ? Only if its null I should be connecting right ??

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to initialize the GoogleApiClient inside a thread inside onCreate?
You can just declare it without a thread.

```
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 mGoogleApiClient=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).
                        addConnectionCallbacks(this).
                        addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).
                        addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
     mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
                        .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                        .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
}
```

then your onResume should work fine.

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        Log.i(TAG, "OnResume, Connected back!");
    }
```

About your comment :

> If its NOT NULL , why should I connect again ? Only if its null I
>   should be connecting right ??

You cannot call connect() from a NULL Object such mGoogleApiClient. Since you initialized it on a separated thread, Android calls onCreate()-->onStart()-->onResume() one after another in this order, so when you reach onResume(), your mGoogleApiClient was not initialized yet by the thread, that's why you got the error. 
Just by initializing a mGoogleApiClient you are NOT CONNECTING ANYTHING! So you need to call connect() if you plan to use any feature from Google Play Service.